# Connect call failed

Tags: ubuntu, port

I wrote a simple app on websocket. On local machine all works good. I deploy a server side on remote server on port 3636. When I try to connect it from same server, all good. From other place there is an error

> Connect call failed.

My ufw is inactive. netstat -tulpn shows:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3636          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      993/python
```

What can I do to open remote access to port 3636?

Comment: what about  iptables ?

Comment: @LinSel ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:3636
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:3636